# Entity Framework - Separate Primary Keys with Nav Props in One-To-One relationship

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity

EF is not being friendly to me.  I need to create a one-to-one relationship that have separate primary keys, while retaining the convenience of navigation properties.   But no matter what I try, EF gives me an error unless I remove the navigation property.

Here's a perfect illustration of the problem.  As you can see, I can't merge primary keys.  And I don't want to simulate a 1..* relationship, because the relationship is always 1-1.

```
public class SingleParent
{
    public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual OnlyChild Child { get; set; }
}

public class OnlyChild
{
    public Guid ChildID { get; set; }
    public virtual SingleParent Parent { get; set; }
}

// Parent and Child cannot share a primary key because a pediatrician only treats children.
public class Pediatrician
{
    public Guid PediatricianID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OnlyChild> Patients;
}
```

How can I get the navigation properties such that Parent.Child <==> Child.Parent? I would prefer to do this with Data Annotations to be consistent with the rest code.  Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, the Pediatrician class is only there for clarification as to why I can't merge the PK for SingleParent and OnlyChild.  You can disregard it as I'm really only interested in activating the Parent <--> Child navigation property.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Foreign Key to both entities it should work with both DataAnnotations and with Fluent API.

```
    public class SingleParent
    {
        public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
        public Guid ChilId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ChildId")]
        public virtual OnlyChild Child { get; set; }
    }

    public class OnlyChild
    {
        public Guid ChildID { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public virtual SingleParent Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

[Here is some documentation](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) that explains how to create a one-to-one relation.

Comment: I wish it were that easy.  But that fails with the following error:
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'EFTestHarness.SingleParent' and 'EFTestHarness.OnlyChild'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: Mmm.. ok.. strange.. is that blog post maybe outdated (since it uses the CTP)?